# Adding where clausule in a store locator mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

First time here on this website but already found a lot of common sense here. But the first time ever i'm stuck, can't find anything about it. Been searching for days to get a solution. But now i can't even get some sleep without thinkin about this stupid little thingy. For my point of view ..

I'm building a website where i need to locate stores, but these stores are based on categories. Now i found the mysql query from the google api docs.

```
$lat = substr($_POST['lat'],0,10);
$lng = substr($_POST['lng'],0,10);
$cat = $_POST['cat'];

$testquery = $db->query("SELECT id, naam, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(".$lat.") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(".$lng.") ) + sin( radians(".$lat.") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM stores HAVING distance < 2 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20");
```

in this case $lat is the latitude, en lng is longtitude.. cat is the category.

I've tried. searched for days where i need to put a where catId = $cat. Because.. it seems impossible. Or ... is there something i'm missing here?

excuse me if i forgot any information to tell, new here so im just bouncing in right here.. hehe

Please help me sleep again.. Thanx in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each store has a category:

```
SELECT id, naam, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(".$lat.") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(".$lng.") ) + sin( radians(".$lat.") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM stores
WHERE catId = $cat
HAVING distance < 2
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Comment: Wauw, i'm really impressed i was such a dumb idiot. Been working on that for DAYS.. believe me.. You are my hero in this case.. Glad you could help me that fast..